# How to substract DateInterval from DateInterval?

Tags: php, datetime

I have two intervals:

```
$intervalFrom = DateInterval('12:00')
$intervalTo = DateInterval('1:30')
```

Output must be:

```
DateInterval('10:30')
```

I try

```
$newInterval =  $intervalFrom->sub($intervalTo);
```

But It not work

Comment: you do not subtract `DateInterval` from `DateInterval`, you subtract `DateInterval` from `DateTime`. Now, if you elaborate on what you need this for, we might actually help you.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: There is no `DateInterval->sub()` method

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 times a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) using `PT12H` and `PT1H30M`.

To get a difference, you could use the DateTime [diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method.

Create 2 datetimes and pass 2 fixed starting points like "midnight" and for both of them add an interval.

Retrieve the number of hours `h` and minutes `i` and use those to create a new DateInterval:

```
$intervalFrom = new DateInterval('PT12H');
$intervalTo = new DateInterval('PT1H30M');
$d1 = new DateTime("midnight");
$d1->add($intervalFrom);
$d2 = new DateTime("midnight");
$d2->add($intervalTo);
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
$strResult = sprintf("PT%sH%sM", $diff->h, $diff->i);
$resultDateInterval = new DateInterval($strResult);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/U2MZG)